# DragDrop - Change Cursor to USER-DEFINED CustomCursor

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, custom-cursor

Maybe I have missed something obvious.  Currently I am using the feedback interrupt to change the cursor to one of the Windows supplied cursors (thanks to being put on the right track by Hans Passant in answer to a previous request for help - thanks).

Instead of using the pre-packaged cursors, is it possible to use my own custom-cursor (icon), and if so - are there any rules re size etc., or can I use something like a png/jpg etc.. ?

Regards,

Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  But it has to be a cursor, it can't be an image.

You can turn an image into an icon with Bitmap.GetHicon() method and pass that to the Cursor class constructor.  It does however a very poor job on images that contain a lot of colors.  The color mapping algorithm is miserable, in general that's something that's hard to do well. It is best to use a good graphics program.  Check my [answer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/36028246-7fc8-4cda-a582-de8a675a0827/) for a trick to use text as a cursor, using the same technique.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it has left me somewhat confused.  Is there a load() method to load a bmp, jpg or pga etc and then convert into the bmp ... so that I can then use the Cursor(bmp(GetHicon()) ?

Comment: Erm, yes, the Bitmap constructor can load images.  Focus on using a cursor to get the best results.